# How to determin if folder already exists in innosetup

Tags: inno-setup

Can you give me instructions how to check if folder already exists (right after the user selected a folder), and if so - prompt him with a similar message to the attached one?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: You could use `function FileOrDirExists(const Name: String): Boolean;` along with `MsgBox` in [Code] section. But in the normal way Inno checks if folder exists automatically.

Comment: @RobeN, `DirExists`, but OP needs to operate with the `DirExistsWarning` directive.

Answer (score 2):

To force this warning to always popup (even when the application was already installed and you're going to install the new version of it into the same folder), you can set the [`DirExistsWarning`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_direxistswarning.htm) to `yes`:

```
[Setup]
...
DirExistsWarning=yes
```

Comment: Note that generally it's a bad idea to warn the user about this on an upgrade, since you *want* them to install into the same folder.  In fact it's typically a good idea to use `DisableDirPage=auto`, which won't even ask them to pick a different folder on an upgrade.

Comment: @Miral, hard to say what is actually asked here. It might be meant to always popup this warning. Maybe is wanted only when the setup is not an update (e.g. because OP has accidentally set `DirExistsWarning` to `no`). Maybe is wanted to popup this warning *"right after the user selected a folder"*, what would require to use `DisableDirPage=no` and intercept `DirEdit.OnChange` event.